# Does Qcoh(X) admit a generating set?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra

Let $X$ be a scheme (or more generally a ringed space, if it works). Does $Qcoh(X)$, the category of quasi-coherent sheaves on $X$, admit a generating set? This would be useful, because then every cocontinuous functor on $Qcoh(X)$ has a right adjoint (SAFT).

If $X$ is affine, then $\mathcal{O}_X$ is a generator. I doubt that this is true in general. If $X$ is quasi-separated, perhaps the direct images of the $\mathcal{O}_U$, $U$ affine, do the job, but the naive proof does not work. If $Qcoh(X)$ does not have a generating set in general, what conditions on $X$ guarantee this?

EDIT: It is true when $X$ is concentrated, i.e. quasi-compact and quasi-separated, in particular when $X$ is noetherian (see Philipp's comment). This is already satisfying. Anyway, are there other (counter)examples?

PS: Note that this question is somehow unnatural with the background of [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/38009/abelian-categories-enriched-over-sheaves); $\underline{Qcoh}(X)$, considered as a stack of abelian categories, always has a "stack-generator", namely $U \mapsto \mathcal{O}_U$. Nevertheless, I think the question above is interesting.

Comment: For a ringed space X the category QCoh(X) need not be abelian. The usual hypothesis on a scheme X which ensures that QCoh(X) is a Grothendieck category is that X be quasi-compact and quasi-separated (this is often called "concentrated"). See [Lipman-Notes on derived functors and Grothendieck duality, 4.1.3.1] (available on his website) for a proof in this case. Also Daniel Murfet's notes are useful and contain a proof, see [http://therisingsea.org/notes/ModulesOverAScheme.pdf, Proposition 66]. I haven't thought about counterexamples in other cases.

Comment: Thank you Philipp ;). The notes of Daniel Murfet are very good (and remind me of the stacks project).

Comment: There are no counterexamples.  For an arbitrary scheme $X$ there exists an infinite cardinal $\kappa$ so that every quasi-coherent sheaf is generated by its quasi-coherent subsheaves of type $\kappa$, where the latter means that sections over some open affine cover (and then necessarily over any open affine) are generated by $\le \kappa$ elements as a module. This was explained to me long ago by Gabber, so ask him for the details.  There is obviously a *set* of isomorphism class representatives for the quasi-coherent sheaves of type $\kappa$, so that settles it affirmatively in general.

Comment: @Brian: Great. Could you post this as an answer?

Comment: Dear Martin: I don't remember how Gabber's argument goes (except that it was "soft", not needing anything deep, just some set-theoretic cleverness -- I think $\kappa$ involves the cardinality of some open affine cover and open affine covers of the double overlaps thereof, and probably other stuff too such as coordinate rings of affine opens), and I don't have time to reconstruct it. I hope someone who is really into such matters may do that, and then they can post it as an appropriate answer.  That will be better. 

Comment: I didn't mean all the details. Anyway, I have emailed Gabber.

Comment: @ Phillip H. Non-abelian categories may still have generators. One does not have much to do with another...

Comment: @ Martin B. Doc, you may think it is bonkers but why don't skyscrapers at all the point form a generating set??? 

Comment: @Bugs: Homomorphisms on skyscapers only give global sections.

Comment: @ M.B. Of course you know, this means war! :-) Me thinking that all you need is to distinguish ($af\neq bf$) a pair of distinct morphisms $a,b:X->Y$ by mapping generator to $f:?->X$. Since $a$ and $b$ are distinct, they are distinct on some stalk $X_t$. So all we need is a generator for each $QCoh_t$, of sheaves supported at $t$. But this seems to be a local question, so we are just talking about modules over a local ring, so some appropriate skyscraper is a generator... Have I totally gone mad?

Comment: It's not local. Check the details and you will run into the problems which are solved in the case of concentrated schemes.

Comment: @Bugs Bunny: The first sentence of my comment refers to an earlier version of the question which mentioned the abelian category QCoh(X).

Comment: Gabber has sent me a scan of a 11 year old letter, which is addressed to BCnrd ;). I will try to write it up. 

Comment: Martin, good to hear!  I probably have the original in a filing cabinet somewhere, but am not sure. If you do get around to typing it up, please email me the .pdf file. Thanks.

Comment: Gabber's argument also appears in print in Enochs and Estrada, "Relative homological algebra in the category of quasi-coherent sheaves," Adv. in Math. 194 (2005) 284--295.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gabber's argument also appears in print in 
[Enochs and Estrada, "Relative homological algebra in the category of quasi-coherent sheaves," Adv. in Math. 194 (2005) 284--295](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2004.06.007).

Comment: This is a great article. It shows more generally that for every quiver $Q$ and every flat ring representation $R$ of $Q$, the category $Qcoh(R)$ is a Grothendieck category. 

Comment: Let me just mention that in the paper you have to replace quivers by small categories and introduce compatiblity conditions in order to get the correct notion of (quasi-coherent) modules. I've already emailed with Enochs about that. The arguments should carry over.

Answer (score 12):

Yes: if $X$ is quasi-compact and quasi-separated, then the category of quasi-coherent sheaves on $X$ is canonically equivalent to the category of ind-objects on the (essentially small) category of coherent sheaves of finite presentation; see the Appendix of Deligne in Hartshorne's *Residues and duality*.

Comment: Perhaps, you can see the work of Neeman, Henning Krause and others on "WELL GENERATED CATEGORY".

Answer (score 12):

As BCnrd already told us in the comments, $Qcoh(X)$ always has a generating set. Klick [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10402546/generator.pdf) for my write-up of Gabber's proof.

Comment: Link seems to be broken