# About condition for structure sheaf of a scheme being compact object in a category of sheaf of module over X

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory, sheaf-theory

I found the condition for one direction :
[Categorical interpretation of quasi-compact quasi-separated schemes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/90055/categorical-interpretation-of-quasi-compact-quasi-separated-schemes)

This article said that if $X$ is quasi compact and quasi separated, $\mathscr{O}_X$ is a compact object in $Qcoh(X)$. A comment said that if the structure sheaf is compact( the global section functor preserves a colimit in $Qcoh(X)$), then $X$ is quasi compact.

Is there any result about quasi-separatedness?

Comment: You are essentially asking the same question as in the linked one. It's a duplicate.